# Saving to and Pulling from user device | python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I've just created my first telegram bot using python-telegram-bot and I couldn't find a way to save text file in a specific directory on the user device, and pull the file out if necessary..
Help anyone?

Comment: That's not how this site works. please revisit the [tour], and read [ask]. [edit] your question with the missing information

Comment: Isn't files and other media content saving automatically on user device? Or at least depend on device and its OS?

Comment: @Kraay89 sorry man, can't get what's missing..

Comment: @wowkin2 The files can be saved pretty easily on the server side but I can't figure a way to save them on the user side and then have access to them..

Comment: You can't have access to them from client-side. Only user can send it to server via chat.

Comment: @BenEz For one: you're missing the part where you show what you've tried.
What you're asking is impossible i think. Telegram (bot) is for sending, managing and interacting with messages. You can't control what happens on the device. It would be a big security no-no, to be able to control a users device. You can play with cosmetics a little(custom keyboard and whatnot), but you can't acces the filesystem, only the user controls that.

Comment: @Kraay89 I want to save some credentials but I don't want to save them on the server side.. I just need to find a way to save the text and access it when necessary.. How is it usually done?

Comment: @BenEz it is usually done on Server Side. Or you can build-in that values into your InlineKeyboardButtons if that can work for you. There is no cookies or any other client-side storage available, only chat (messages and keyboard).